# Spring Roo 2.0.0M1 <textarea> instead of <input> tags

Tags: spring, input, textarea, roo

New to Roo, created an app with STS and the resulting forms from the Entity (see code below), I get `<textarea>` tags instead of `<input>` tags, why is that? Is they a way to force input tags?

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@Configurable
public class DataSource {

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String name;

    /**
     */
    @Size(max = 2000)
    private String description;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@Length(max = 2000)` instead of `@Size(max = 2000)`

When I remember right, Roo 1.x switched form input to textara when the max length was greather than some threshold.

Comment: +1 That did the trick. @Length still restricts the persistence side but does not force the "<textarea>" in the view. Well done, thanks.